# Can we answer to a Question when the Question is Closed

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I came across this **[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539029/spliting-a-string-char-into-a-char-in-c)**

[image]

Is it possible or some kind or a **bug**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not a bug. If a user started writing an answer and in the meanwhile the question was closed, the user would be allowed to post the answer. This is by-design. Stack Exchange does not want anybody's effort in writing an answer to get wasted.

Comment: Seems logical and valid.